# Sql Server connection timeout

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-timeout

I'm trying to execute a sql server query through asp.net but the following exception occurs : 
**"Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."**

My connection string timeout is 300000 and remote query timeout in sql server is 60000 
how can i solve this problem

Comment: Could you provide some details: how do you connect, where SQL server is located, how to you get this error: after the timeout or when you starting the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the command timeout, i solved the problem with the following line of code :

`command.CommandTimeout = 30000;`

but the question now : how can i set commandTimeout default value over the application

Answer (score 0):

I seems you have a blocked table. You can exec sp_lock to see who is blocking what.

If there is no blocking, then you have a query really bad constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Please extend the script execution timeout in web.config file.

```
<!-- Increase script execution timeout  -->
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" /> <!-- its 5 min -->
</system.web>
```

Hope, this will resolve your issue.

Thanks,
Rohit